# How can I get the oauth_token data from my backend when it's sent via a http response to my frontend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am using react-twitter-auth as part of my OAuth 1.0a user authentication flow on my site. My goal is to authenticate a user and then access their username. So far I have a bunch of code I borrowed from a website. There is client side code and backend code.

The client starts the authentication flow, sending a request to `http://localhost:4000/api/v1/auth/twitter/reverse`. There, I see from a console.log statement that I have the `oauth_token` value that I will need later for step 3 of the so-called "3 legged auth" authentication flow that I am going through.

Here is the server route I am hitting:

```
router.route("/auth/twitter/reverse").post(function (req, res) {
  console.log(72);
  request.post(
    {
      url: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
      oauth: {
        oauth_callback: "http://localhost:3000/",
        consumer_key: twitterConfig.consumerKey,
        consumer_secret: twitterConfig.consumerSecret,
      },
    },
    function (err, r, body) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err, 83);
        return res.send(500, { message: e.message });
      }

      var jsonStr =
        '{ "' + body.replace(/&/g, '", "').replace(/=/g, '": "') + '"}';
      console.log(jsonStr, 88);
      res.send(JSON.parse(jsonStr));
    }
  );
});
```

I get values such as:

```
{ "oauth_token": "HnQ1SgAAAAAAAABco", "oauth_token_secret": "y1qeyxZeiCEWqkKz9y", "oauth_callback_confirmed": "true"} 88
```

Some characters have been deleted in case that isn't data I should be exposing. Anyway:

I need that "oauth_token" value to make it to my client. Why? Because I'm getting a pin in the 3 legged auth part, and so I need both values to arrive on my server at the same time.

If i wasn't using the react-twitter-auth library, I would have no problem here, because I would just be sending a http request via fetch, and so I would have a `.then()` block to show me what the value of `res.send(JSON.parse(jsonStr));` is on the frontend. But I don't have that, nothing is there to listen for the `res.send()` part. How can I listen for it?

Thanks

edit: I am critical of this library because it doesn't account for what happens with the PIN based strategy for 3 legged auth.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at react-twitter-auth codebase I'm not sure they support 3 legged auth as they are calling [authenticate endpoint](https://github.com/GenFirst/react-twitter-auth/blob/master/src/index.js#L38) instead of authorize endpoint as stated in [the documentation of twitter api](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/obtaining-user-access-tokens#:%7E:text=3-legged%20authorization,having%20them%20authorize%20your%20application.)

I would either try [react-twitter-oauth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-twitter-oauth) forked from reacr-twitter-auth or go through the twitter documentation to implement it myself